# 22.04 Apt update failed to fetch

Tags: apt, 22.04, update-manager, apt-mirror

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 on my pc, but every time I wrote `sudo apt update`, it always kept saying:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried using multiple local mirrors and the main one too.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

[EDIT]

Here's the /etc/apt/sources.list

[etc/apt/sources.list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Uwz.png)

Comment: Please show your /etc/apt/sources.list in the question.

Comment: This is an internet connection problem.

Comment: @DanielT I pinged 8.8.8.8 and it got a response so there is internet connection.

Comment: Do you see anything if you paste http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease into a browser?